# vi - finding a pattern in lines and add ";" at the end of those lines

Tags: sed, vim

I want to add `;` in the end of lines in a txt file containing ddl for multiple tables.

For example :

```
LOCATION:
 'hdfs://HDP**/apps/hive/warehouse/bps_uat.db/maaa'
```

As per above, I need to add `;` in the end of all such lines.

Comment: Where should the `;` be added? After `LOCATION:` or `maaa'` or both? If after `maaa'`, can we assume that each line contains `'hdfs://` as prefix and the line starts with a space character? Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/543451/edit) your question and provide some more examples as input with the desired output. Do you need `vim` or would any standard unix tool be fine?

Comment: Thanks for the response @Freddy.
I need to add ; after /maa'; in vim
There are multiple lines that start with space character but yes for this line, it starts with a space and 'hdfs://

Comment: This file contains ddl for 400 tables and you can say I need to add ; in the end of each table ddl. In this case, the end of each ddl is with the lines in my question.

Comment: @SweetyP Rather than adding comments, you should [edit] the question to include all relevant details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to Freddy's answer, you can use the `:global` command. For example:

```
:g/maaa/norm A;
```

Which means:

```
:g/      " On each line matching this regex:
maaa     " 'maaa'
norm A;  " Run 'A;' as if I had manually typed
```

You'll have to adjust 'maaa' to whatever you need, since it's not clear from your question which lines you want to apply this to. `:g/hdfs/norm A;` for example will append a semicolon to any line containing the text "hdfs".

Comment: Oh yes this works as well. Thanks @DJMcMayhem !!

Comment: @SweetyP Happy to help :) Also, if you have more vim questions, there is a dedicated [stackexchange site for vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4):

To add a `;` to all lines ending with `maaa'`, you could use the following substitution.   Press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, then enter

```
:%s/maaa'$/&;/
```

Explanation:

- `:%s/` replace one each line
- `maaa'$` match `maaa'` at the end of the line `$`
- `/&;/` replace with the matched pattern and `;`

---

To add a `;` to all lines starting with a space and `'hdfs://` and ending with a `'`, you could use the following substitution. Again, press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, then enter

```
:%s/^ 'hdfs:\/\/.*'$/&;/
```

Explanation:

- `:%s/` replace one each line
- `^ 'hdfs:\/\/.*'$` match the beginning of the line `^`, followed by a space character, followed by `hdfs://` (`/` need to be escaped with a `\`), followed by any character `.*`, followed by `'` and the end of the line `$`
- `/&;/` replace with the matched pattern and `;`

You can always undo an operation with <kbd>Esc</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> if something went wrong.

Comment: I tried the last option without ^ and it worked !! Thanks a lot for the answer Freddy.

Comment: @SweetyP That command definitely works. You may have typed it wrong, or maybe you have trailing whitespace

Comment: :%s/ 'hdfs:\/\/.*'$/&;/   
worked.