# Search and Modify strings with Vim

Tags: regular-expression, vim

I wish to find lines containing a digit string only and modify each match by putting it in between a pair of square brackets ([..]) in Vim.

e.g. Original text

```
10001
hostname1
hostname2
10002
hostname3
hostname4
10003
hostname5
hostname6
...
```

Change it to:

```
[10001]
hostname1
hostname2
[10002]
hostname3
hostname4
[10003]
hostname5
hostname6
...
```

I can catch each digit lines using regex:

> ^\d*$

but don't know how to put the result in between [..] in Vim. 
Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Do not know if this helps since I don't use vim, but in others text editors, in this case xed, this work: find `(^\d+$)` replace `[\1]`

Comment: See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/543472/332764) (maybe a duplicate). You only need to insert your regex and `/[&]/` as the replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
:%s/\(^\d*$\)/[\1]/
```

Comment: Thank you guillermo! This works, too! Am I right that the search term has to be grouped (...) in order for it to work?

Comment: @cody You could also use `&` to reference the whole match: `:%s/^\d*$/[&]/`, that's what I meant in my comment. But if you only need a part of a pattern, then yes, groups and backreferences is the way to do it.

Comment: @Freddy thank you so much! that's even easier to grip!

Answer (score 3):

You can substitute the number string and carry it forward into the replacement string.

```
%s/^\(\d*\)$/\[\1\]/
```